# my phpMyAdmin data is hashed or hexed?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, phpmyadmin

I have a mySQL db setup in MAMP in which I connected mySQL Workbench to administer the design of the database.

When I inserted some data today from within myPhpAdmin (localhost:8888), I noticed the data was being displayed with hashed or hex values.

Here is a screen of the table view which you can see the odd display and text format offering a link to download (never seen this).

[image]

If I edit a record, the data is properly displayed.

[image]

But if I export the data, the values look to be hexadecimal.

[image]

Is my install hosed? Or did mySQL Workbench do something?
Thanks for any answers here.

Rich

Comment: I presume the column's datatype is BLOB and that you probably want something like CLOB instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459029/phpmyadmin-displaying-varchar-fields-as-individual-hex-values-in-table-view):

> "varchar fields were set to utf8_bin and needed to be changed to
>   utf8_general_ci"

Comment: That was it. Strange the table was set to general_ci, not sure why the fields would end up as bin. Thank you @jynus!